# Task is only assigning to first person of group while assigning to a group through "People/Group" column

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, groups

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 List Workflow to assign a task to a group. I have a condition based on a **Country** column, such as if the Country is **US** then it should assign a task to *AccountsUS* group, else if the Country of the author is *AccountsIndia*, then it should assign the task to India group.

---

I don't want to do it like this [image: Conditional assignment].
I have also tried by creating a "People/Group" column, but the task is assigned to the only first person of that group.
 Kindly suggest how can we create such dynamic workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Online, I will suggest you to use Power Automate to do the work. You can use case statement to handle such situation.

https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-to-build-multiple-conditions-in-microsoft-flow/

Comment: Sure, for now, I got my mistake... I was taking People/Group field value in a local variable, thus assigning the task to the first person of the group.